# Why sphere and torus are not homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

I heard that two objects are homeomorphic if one could be deformed into the other by continuous transformation. [For example in this link](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/%7Ejohn/MT4521/Lectures/L21.html), it is shown

> a  sphere and a torus are not homeomorphic
>
> "Proof"
> Removing a circle from a sphere always splits it into two parts -- not so for the torus.

However, I may imagine the following operations

[image]

to let the points around the inner circle of the continuous torus merge to a sphere. I see no reason merging is not continuous.  Why not this transformation follow the definition of homeomorphic?

Comment: "Removing a(n embedded) circle from a sphere always splits it into two parts" is nontrivial, FYI: it's the Jordan curve theorem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because when you merge many points into a single one, you do not have a bijection; a homeomorphism is a continuous map with a continuous inverse, and a non-bijective map cannot have a (two-sided) inverse.

Besides, if this operation was a homeomorphism, then its inverse --tearing a circle to turn it into a torus would be a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 6):

Intuitively, homeomorphisms do not allow tearing or gluing. This is because they and their inverse need to be continuous :

1. Gluing breaks injectivity, hence it breaks continuity.
2. Tearing breaks continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Even ignoring the invertibility issues, your map doesn't turn the torus into a sphere. It turns the torus into a sphere with a wall in it.

Comment: (perhaps you mean the ball and the solid torus?)