# Proof that torus not homeomorphic to sphere by topological means

Tags: general-topology

> (...) if two topological objects have different homotopy
> groups, they can't have the same topological structure—a fact that may
> be difficult to prove using only topological means. For example, the
> torus is different from the sphere: the torus has a "hole"; the sphere
> doesn't.

From the wikipedia article. The homotopy group proof is indeed pretty simple. The article claims it's "difficult" to prove using only topological means. How can this be proved using topological means (without homotopy theory etc.)?

Comment: One could use Euler characteristic-like arguments.

Comment: The torus $\mathbb{T}^2$ is not simply connected, whereas the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ is.

Comment: You can refer to this link : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847929/why-sphere-and-torus-are-not-homeomorphic

Comment: See here for a proof https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3431989/homeomorphism-between-s1%c3%97s1-and-s2/3432013#3432013

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: "simply connected" is a homotopy concept. The OP is wondering about a proof that _doesn't_ use homotopy.

Comment: @Troposphere Sorry, I read "homology" for a reason :)

Comment: If you want the best proof that uses topological means, it might help to understand that "homotopy theory" is a topological theory. If you took the standard proof that uses "homotopy theory", and replaced all occurrences of "homotopy" concepts with their topological definitions, then you would have a very good topological proof (except it would be expressed in more words due to avoiding the "h" word).

Comment: A cleaner statement would be "without using tools of algebraic topology" rather than "only topological means."

Comment: @Randall: You are leaving aside a proof of topological invariance of the Euler characteristic. The usual proof goes via homology theory. There is an alternative argument, but it is quite hard, requires a proof of uniqueness of PL structure on surfaces.

Answer (score 5):

Use the Jordan curve theorem, if there was a homeomorphism $\phi: S^1 \times S^1 \rightarrow S^2$ the curve $\gamma:S^1 \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1$ given by $\gamma(s) = (1,s)$ would get taken to a Jordan curve in $S^2$. The Jordan curve theorem says that the complement of the image of $\phi \circ \gamma$ is not connected however the complement of the image of $\gamma$ is clearly connected.

Thus $S^2$ and $S^1 \times S^1$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: It's all correct but Jordan curve theorem is a hard result: Much harder result than proving nontriviality of the fundamental group of the torus and triviality of the fundamental group of the sphere.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Right, but that's not what he asked for... so I fail to see what your point is

Comment: Admittedly, the question in OP is very sloppy, but it is asking for a "topological proof," which presumably means a proof which does not use any tools of algebraic topology. For completeness of the answer, you should either provide a proof of Jordan Curve Theorem which avoids such tools or give a reference to such a proof. This is the point of my comment.